# Take input text, print to page and open new window onclick

Tags: javascript, function, input, variables, window

What I need help with:

My page shall take user input text, then show what was entered on the page (no alert) and open a new window on click if a match is found that would be stored in an array or var.

---

Here is the line I am having trouble with below:

```
 onclick="insert(this.form.name.value),show();"/>
```

---

Here is the code thus far:

Input

```
        var array = new Array();

        function insert(val){
            array[array.length]=val;
        }

        function show() {
            var string="<b>All Element of the Array :</b><br>";
            for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                string =string+array[i]+"<br>";
            }
            if(array.length > 0)
                document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = string;
        }


function open_win(){

window.open ,"_blank","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, 

copyhistory=no, width=200, height=305")
}

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>Input</h2>
    <form name="form1">

        <table width="407">
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right"><b>Name</b>
                <td width="9"><b>&nbsp;:</b>
                <td width="224">
                <input type="text" name="name"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td width="154" align="right">
                <td width="9">
                <td width="224">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="154" align="right">
                <td width="9">
                <td width="224">
                <input type="button" Value="Print Name to page and open new window" 
                       onclick="insert(this.form.name.value),show();"/>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help,

Michael

Comment: Sorry,forgot the main thrust of the question.
I need to store data via a var with some value and "whatever the value user inputs"checks and prints to page and new window only opens if there is a input match.

Comment: You can edit your own post, so add the real question there so everybody can see it.

Comment: Thanks just found that button

Answer (score 1):

Try using a semicolon rather than a comma. You want to execute the first function, and then the second one.

```
onclick="insert(this.form.name.value); show(); return false;"
```

You add the `return false;` so that the link will not be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Call the subsequent functions from inside the insert() function. Then return true/false to indicate if the browser should follow the link or not.